# Symfony 4 - FatalErrorException, Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, symfony4

It's new app in Symfony 4.

Didn't make any changes.

And this happens

[image]

"Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"?

I heard symfony 4 is ultra fast.

Laravel is ultra slow and I have no problem with that.

But this fresh symfony app can't load properly?

What is the problem?

It's fresh symfony 4 app installed with `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project`

And I have win 7 x64 + newest xampp with php 7.2

Comment: It's probably caching. See: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-cache-clear-with-warmup

Comment: Sounds more like an environment variable sort of thing.  Does "php bin/console server:start" work as expected?  And no, Symfony 4 is not ultra fast and Laravel is not ultra slow.  They both perform reasonably well when configured properly.

Comment: This must not happen, average response time on big apps is usually 500ms in development environment, on warmed cache. It looks like cache warming is broken somehow; did you add anything to this application?

Also, make sure you installed 4.2. Previous version failed due to bug in opcache, maybe it is related to your problem: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29364

Answer (score 2):

**Error:** 
It is not a symfony error. It is rather a php error. PHP has default 30 seconds of execution time and if your symfony app does not run on 30 seconds, maximum execution error is thrown.

To change this, go to your `php.ini` file in `xampp/php` and search for `max_execution_time` and change it to your desired time of execution.

**Fast Execution:** 
I also find it slow while executing app for first time but refreshing or editing same page is pretty fast (which works out in production). It is probably Symfony uses front controller design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem.

After any changes in the project perform:

```
server:restart
```

It is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In public/index.php you need to comment out.

```
if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}
```

It solved a problem for me.

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzXgL.jpg)